# Mutation step-size in genetic algorithm

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming, mutation

Can someone explain to me what means "mutation step size" ?
I'm reading an article regarding genetic algorithms and it says:

"the mutation randomly changes the decision of
a node or mutate the value with a step-size of 0.25"

I know the role of mutation in GA life cycle , but I can't find a good explanation for what is step size of mutation.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially it's how far a mutation can be away from the last value.

"As far as real-valued search spaces are concerned, mutation is normally performed by adding a normally distributed random value to each vector component. The step size or mutation strength (i.e. the standard deviation of the normal distribution) is often governed by self-adaptation (see evolution window)."

That's complex talk for given a vector you are mutating (say X = [x1,x2,..,xN]) then you'll modify that vector's values by some random amount that won't be more than the mutation step size.  So say we had a function called normal(v,stdDev) that generated random values with a normal distribution around some value with stdDev.  Then we'd modify each value of that vector with the following psuedo code:

```
for x in X {
   x = normal(x,mutationStepSize)
}
```

Comment: Yes, normal distribution is common, but the meaning of "step size" relly depends on the mutation algorithm. It might as well be that a uniformly generated number from interval [-0.25, 0.25] is added to the original nubmer. I think that, without further knowledge of the mutation algorithm, it really onl is a strength of the mutation in general.

Comment: That's exactly what I said and what the pseudo code I wrote indicates.

Comment: @chubbsondbus Yes, I just wanted to emphasize that it is not related specifically to the normal distribution.